# Changing a form from a separate background worker

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port

I have a form which when loaded starts a looping background worker which gets data from a usb device every half a second.
Once the program receives a new piece of data from the usb device it runs a function.
The `_Dowork` function has

```
while (true)
{
    portConnection.Write("?");
    Thread.Sleep(50);
}
```

I then have a separate routine that runs when data is received

```
private void portConnection_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

This is the routine that cannot then set values on the original form as the function is apparently on a separate thread.
How can I make this routine able to influence the original form?

Comment: Look at `Invoke` and `InvokeRequired`

Comment: Try something like 

    if (portConnection.InvokeRequired)
    {
         portConnection.Write("?");
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
private void InvokeIfRequired(Control target, Delegate methodToInvoke)
{
    if (target.InvokeRequired)
        target.Invoke(methodToInvoke);
    else
        methodToInvoke.DynamicInvoke();
}
```

Call the method in your `ProcessStatsReceived` and in the `methodToInvoke` do your stuff...

You can use it like this in the ProccessStatusReceived:

```
InvokeIfRequired(this, new MethodInvoker(delegate() { this.lblStatus.Text = (string)e.Data; }));
```

Comment: the target being the main form or the individual object I am trying to use?

Comment: It's the form. I added an example to the answer

Comment: Works perfectly, As the data comes in to one function before being forwarded to another I have just done the above InvokeIfRequired(this, new MethodInvoker(delegate() { this.sensorLocationUpdated();}));

Answer (score 0):

The report progress part of BackgroundWorker is made for this.

This will make the DoWork method able to call a method on the GUI thread.

See this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) article for details.

In short, the needed parts are:

Bind the progress changed handler:

```
bw.ProgressChanged += bw_ProgressChanged;
```

Set the BW to allow progress reporting:

```
bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
```

Implement the progress change method:

```
private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
  //your logic to be executed on the GUI thread here
}
```

Then call it from DoWork like this:

```
bw.ReportProgress( progressPercentage, userState )
```

`progressPercentage` and `userState` can be user to transfer data from the background thread to the `ProgressChanged` method on the GUI thread.