# Change text on a form from within a thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms, textbox

I'm trying to change the text on my Form1's textbox to "hello there" from within a thread.
But when I execute it, I get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
When I check I see that txtboxCheckedFiels has a Null value.

How would I create an Object of that txtbox? (I have multiple threads running of which all should be able to change that text.

Code I've tried:

```
txtboxCheckedFiles.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    txtboxCheckedFiles.Text = "Hello there";
                }));
```

And another way i tried

```
var t = new Thread(
o => 
{
     txtboxCheckedFiles.BeginInvoke(
         ((Action)(() => txtboxCheckedFiles.Text = "Hello there")));
});
```

Comment: Please have a look at my answer in this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842373/changing-a-form-from-a-separate-background-worker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you MUST check if invokation is required, and then you may invoke it.
Also, consider checking that there is a handle to the window, which means that windows is up and running (eg. this will fail if you try to load data in the constructor of the form)

```
if (this.InvokeRequired)
{
    IAsyncResult result = BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
    {
        // DOSTUFF
    }));

    // wait until invocation is completed
    EndInvoke(result);
}
else if (this.IsHandleCreated)
{
    // DO STUFF
}
```

Comment: Think I'm doing something wrong.. My code doesn't go into One of your if statements.

Comment: I think under Normal circumstances this answer of yours will work. So for all other purposes, you have answered the question I asked.
I'll try and find the bug in my code.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It might be the same .. but this is what I've always used :

```
    public void LabelWrite(string value)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
            Invoke(new LabelWriteDelegate(LabelWrite), value);
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = value;
        }
    }
    delegate void LabelWriteDelegate(string value);
```

works like a charm .. you can basically write whatever you want in the else { } too.

Comment: I think something else is wrong.. I still get that error message in your else.. Dont know why though.

Comment: you are using the LabelWrite( some string ) function in that other thread right :?

Comment: Yup, its strange, it works with my manually created threads (your method) but when i try and use this method in a thread pool, it doesnt want to work. [An example is this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as(v=vs.80).aspx) thread pool, its just in a console app, mine is in a windows one obviously.